# Eloquent sub-query for if the row is the latest one

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following subquery:

```
->whereHas('statuses', function($query){
           $query->where('status_id', request('status'));
})->orderBy(...)->paginate();
```

For simplicity's sake I have hidden the full query. Let's say I have the pivot table `user_status`. User has many statuses and a status can also have many users (unusual, I know. Just consider it as an example). So when I query the pivot table `user_status` as described above, I get those rows that have the requested status id. But I also want to add the constraint that the row must be the latest one for that particular user (not in entire table). Here is how the user_status table looks like:

```
+---------+-----------+---------------------+
| user_id | status_id | created_at          |
+---------+-----------+---------------------+
|       1 |         1 | 2018-09-03 18:39:14 |
|       1 |         8 | 2018-09-03 18:51:42 |
+---------+-----------+---------------------+
```

In this scenario, if the requested `status` is `1`, I don't want this row to be returned, because `status_id` 1 is not the latest one for the `user_id` 1 (see the time difference in `create_at` column).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You should query for MAX(status_id) or ORDER BY status_id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: @Alberto Maybe not. I am not determining the latest status by the `status_id`, I have to do it with `created_at`

Comment: Changing `status_id` with `created_at` won't work?

Comment: No. I need the status_id also. Two constraints: The row should match the status_id and the row should be the latest for the user_id

Comment: Ok, so, how many variables do you have? status_id and user_id? The question is how can you do it using the Laravel way (e.g. how to edit the code you posted to make the query happens or do you need to understand the logic to generate the query)?

Comment: if you put where status_id =1 then how you reproduce given result where  status_id = 8 also shown in output. It is not clear. what you want ?

Comment: @SapnaBhayal the given example is just the output of the sql query `select * from user_status`. It's only purpose is to let you know what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by using another condition with a nested query.

```
->whereHas('statuses', function($query){
       $query->where('status_id', request('status'))
             ->whereIn('user_status.id', function($query) {
                $query->selectRaw('MAX(id)')
                      ->from('user_status')
                      ->groupBy('user_id');
             });
})->orderBy(...)->paginate();
```

The nested query will select only latest rows(assuming user_status.id is `auto-increment`)

Comment: `App\User::whereHas()`. It still returns the user when I pass 1 as status. But it should not. Since status_id 1 *is not* the latest status for user_id 1.

Comment: Did you put the nested query?

Comment: Yes I did. I recommend you open up tinker and try it yourself

Comment: Yes, but I don't have all those models!

Comment: `User: classic laravel user model`,
`Status: name, id, created_at`,
`UserStatus: user_id, status_id, created_at`. Also don't forget to put the many-to-many relationship methods: `users` and `statuses` on respective models.

Comment: @Eisenheim have updated the answer. `->where('status_id', request('status'))` should be outside the `whereIn`.

Comment: Also you need to verify the pivot table name: user_status/status_user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179373/discussion-between-im-tsm-and-eisenheim).

Answer (score 0):

I define a relation in user model as :-

```
public function latest_statuses() {
        return $this->hasMany(Status::class,'user_id','id')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->take(1);
}
```

And after that written query as :-

```
$status = \App\User::with('latest_statuses')->whereHas('latest_statuses', function($query){
           return $query->where('status_id', 1);
        })->get();
```

It works for me.

Comment: Isn't that the same thing as this: `->whereHas('statuses', function($query){
                $query->where('status_id', request('status'))->orderBy('user_status.created_at','DESC')->take(1);
            })`

Comment: No, it is not equal. I tried both and found different results set. You can try your own.